# Splinter and Beautiful Soup - extract elements in <section>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to scrape all stats from a football match using `splinter` and `Beautiful Soup` combined.

This is the match url:

```
https://www.premierleague.com/match/46862
```

Then I click on the tab 'stats' and inspect it. This is code I used so far in order to scrape the first section, 'Head-to-Head', which has a `<div>` with `class_='headToHeadTable headToHeadTableLeft'`.

```
browser = Browser("chrome", **executable_path, headless=False)
# get page for a given match
match_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46862'
browser.visit(match_url)

match_tabs = 'li[class="matchCentreSquadLabelContainer"]' # <---- after inspection
browser.find_by_tag(match_tabs).click()
# sort the HTML
match = BeautifulSoup(browser.html, 'html.parser')
# get all stats from game
stats_tab = match.findAll('div', class_='mcTabs')

# HEAD_TO_HEAD
head_to_head = stats_tab[0].findAll('div', class_='statDetails')
# team at left side
team_left = stats_tab[0].find('div', class_='headToHeadTable headToHeadTableLeft')
team_left_name = team_left.find('a', class_='team').text
team_left_stat_names = team_left.findAll('div', class_='stat')
team_left_stat_counts = team_left.findAll('div', class_='count')
# team at right side
team_right = stats_tab[0].find('div', class_='headToHeadTable headToHeadTableRight')
team_right_name = team_right.find('a', class_='team').text
team_right_stat_names = team_right.findAll('div', class_='stat')
team_right_stat_counts = team_right.findAll('div', class_='count')
```

Then the following scrapes my desired results:

```
print ('HEAD TO HEAD')
print ('------------')
print(team_left_name)
for stat in team_left_stat_names:
    print (stat.text)
for stat in team_left_stat_counts:
    print (stat.text)

print(team_right_name)
for stat in team_right_stat_names:
    print (stat.text)
for stat in team_right_stat_counts:
    print (stat.text)
```

But there's much more to it, though, as shown by the HTML image below.

[image]

I would also like to scrape 'Recent Meetings' col, 'Form Guide', 'Season So Far' and "Top Player Stats' above, each one lying in its own "wrapper col-12" `<div>` class.

But I'm not managing to scrape `<tr>` in each respective `<table>`, because each one has a different `<section>`, contrary to Head-To-Head, which has a `<div>` class I can look for.

---

Is there an efficient way of scraping all `<p>` element texts inside those sections?